# Docker client certificate issue

Tags: openssl, docker

I'm using the docker rest client API to write my client that would connect to the docker daemon remote. I followed the steps mentioned in the documentation mentioned on this page:

https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

and generated the needed certificates.

Now when I try with my client, I get failure messages with the following message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

I then tried to print what is written in the CN name of my certifiate and here is what I see:

```
joes@joes:~$ keytool -printcert -v -file server-cert.pem
Owner: CN=123.456.0.10
Issuer: CN=123.456.0.10, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=IN
Serial number: 2
Valid from: Mon Nov 24 19:13:49 CET 2014 until: Sun Dec 19 19:13:49 CET 2055
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  80:72:7B:43:21:37:BE:48:20:D4:E8:94:6D:2C:73:51
     SHA1: 36:9C:FB:D9:1E:1B:3F:D6:1C:32:6C:ED:F0:C6:88:95:44:1A:A4:20
     SHA256: 49:C9:FD:39:29:D7:CF:78:14:49:86:47:CC:B5:F7:18:D3:B9:96:E5:34:52:6A:01:A6:88:1D:4B:E0:33:1B:D9
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 1
```

Now when I did the same for my cert.pem file, I see the following:

```
joes@joes:~$ keytool -printcert -v -file cert.pem
Owner: CN=client
Issuer: CN=123.456.0.10, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=IN
Serial number: 3
Valid from: Mon Nov 24 19:16:06 CET 2014 until: Sun Dec 19 19:16:06 CET 2055
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  A9:7D:56:69:FA:BD:01:40:CB:CB:C6:B6:BE:FD:EB:9F
     SHA1: 24:1D:96:7E:02:26:D0:2B:14:F6:F2:7B:ED:7F:9C:06:1F:1D:91:81
     SHA256: E9:15:C5:53:FC:E9:EB:5F:62:1D:34:CB:85:AB:B1:E8:9D:19:11:F0:34:04:AA:19:48:BA:CD:2A:ED:AA:90:47
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  clientAuth
]
```

I can see that the CN is different, but what should it be? Should it be the CN of the server on which my docker daemon in running? If so why does the docker documentation has the following:

```
For client authentication, create a client key and certificate signing request:

$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out key.pem 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
...............................................+++
...............................................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
$ openssl req -subj '/CN=**client**' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
```

Which certificates should I set in docker daemon and which ones are for the client? It is not that clear from the docker documentation!